# PeriodicBoundaryConditions an a square

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I hope the answer is simple, but I can't see the solution:

I want to solve a PDE for `u[x,y]` under Periodic boundary conditions on say a square size 10 x 10. I.e. `u[0,y]=u[10,y]` etc. 
 I'd like to use the [`NDEigensystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html) function (and it works with Dirichlet conditions) but can't get it working for PBC's. 
I tried the following:
`pbc2 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == 0, y == 0, 
 TranslationTransform[{10, 10}]]`

--> No success with `NDEigensystem`.

Defining the PBC's in 2 parts (i.e. `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], y == 0, TranslationTransform[{10}]]` ) etc. and plug those as a list into `NDEigensystem` does not work either.

So in short: How do I specify in Mathematica 11 Periodic Boundary conditions for 2 variables?

edit: The code in total:
OK, here is the total code:
`\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}];`
`B = 5.0;
sigma = 1
newPot[x_, y_] := -0.5*Exp[-1*(x^2 + y^2)/sigma];`
`A = B {0, x}; L = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
  I Div[A, {x, y}] u[x, y] + 2 I A.D[u[x, y], {{x, y}}] + 
  A.A u[x, y] + newPot[x, y] u[x, y];`
`B = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True];{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{L], \B]}, 
u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \Omega], 6];`

What I want to do is to replace the Dirichlet-Condition with a PeriodicBoundaryCondition...

Comment: If you clearly lay out what you've tried, with code, some sample function for `u`, etc. people will be much more apt to help you. As is, I would argue you don't provide enough to convince someone that it's worth their time.

Comment: OK, here is the total code\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}];
B = 5.0;
sigma = 1
newPot[x_, y_] := -0.5*Exp[-1*(x^2 + y^2)/sigma];
A = B {0, x}; L = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
  I Div[A, {x, y}] u[x, y] + 2 I A.D[u[x, y], {{x, y}}] + 
  A.A u[x, y] + newPot[x, y] u[x, y];
B = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True];

Comment: Ok : Here is what I want to do: